# Mail PHP - Enviando sem informações

Tags: php

Fiz um formulário em **PHP** com *Captcha do Google*. Tudo funciona. Se alguém envia o e-mail via formulário, chega perfeito, tem required, etc.
O problema é que os spans acessam a página do e-mail no site, exemplo *"www.site.com.br/enviar-email.php"*.

Tem como colocar um código dentro do mesmo arquivo impedindo que acessem essa página ou impedindo que o código funcione porque os campos estão vazios?

Esse é o código:

```
 <?


function post_captcha($user_response) {
        $fields_string = '';
        $fields = array(
            'secret' => '____aqui a secret key____',
            'response' => $user_response
        );
        foreach($fields as $key=>$value)
        $fields_string .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
        $fields_string = rtrim($fields_string, '&');

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        return json_decode($result, true);
    }

    // Call the function post_captcha
    $res = post_captcha($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);

    if (!$res['success']) {
        // What happens when the CAPTCHA wasn't checked
        echo '<p>Please go back and make sure you check the security CAPTCHA box.</p><br>';
    } else {
        // If CAPTCHA is successfully completed...

        // Paste mail function or whatever else you want to happen here!
        echo '<br><p>CAPTCHA was completed successfully!</p><br>';
    }

    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $fone = $_POST['telefone'];
    $email = $_POST['endereco'];
    $assunto = $_POST['assunto'];
    $msg = $_POST['msg'];

    $conteudo = "<table width='600' border='0' cellspacing='2' cellpadding='2'>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan='1' align='center'><h3><em>Assunto do E-mail</em></h3></td>
                    </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td width='30%' bgcolor='#f0f0f0'><strong>Nome:</strong></td>
                            <td>$nome</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width='30%' bgcolor='#f0f0f0'><strong>Telefone:</strong></td>
                            <td>$fone</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width='30%' bgcolor='#f0f0f0'><strong>Email:</strong></td>
                            <td>$email</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width='30%' bgcolor='#f0f0f0'><strong>Assunto:</strong></td>
                            <td>$assunto</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width='30%' bgcolor='#f0f0f0'><strong>Mensagem:</strong></td>
                            <td>$msg</td>
                        </tr>
                </table>";
    $seuemail = "teste@teste.com.br";
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
    $headers .= "From:".$email." \r\n"; 
    $assunto = $assunto;

    $enviar = mail($seuemail, $assunto, $conteudo, $headers); 

    if($enviar) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('Contato Enviado com Sucesso!'); window.location.href='contato.php'; </script>";
    }else{
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('Ocorreu algum erro ao enviar o formul&aacute;rio'); </script>";
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Como você valida o Captcha do Google ao enviar o e-mail? No código postado parece não ter esta verificação.

Comment: Olá @AndersonCarlosWoss, atualizei o código! Antes do <button> eu insiro a <div class="g-recaptcha"> e o <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=pt-BR'></script>

Mas para o testes que estou realizando com a resposta do LipESprY eu retirei o captcha.

Comment: Mas desta forma o e-mail será enviado mesmo que o captcha seja inválido, pois a função de envio está fora do `if/else`. Ou você adiciona um `die(...)` dentro do `if` para interromper a execução, ou coloca o restante do código, que faz o envio, dentro do `else`, como o próprio comentário indica: `Paste mail function or whatever else you want to happen here!`.

Comment: Nossa... Mais simples do que eu imaginava @AndersonCarlosWoss, falta de leitura sobre o código, mesmo sendo leigo em PHP. Muito obrigado, dessa forma quando a página de envio é acessada direta por spans, ele diz para voltar e realizar o Captcha.

Comment: Exatamente. A solução dada por LipESprY nas respostas é interessante, mas não completamente funcional, pois só trata se os dados são nulos. Se um sistema de spam fizer requisições ao seu arquivo com dados não nulos, o e-mail seria enviado igualmente. Verificando o captcha, como dito, contorna este problema.

Comment: Entendi! Também achei interessante a resposta dada por ele, há algum tempo queria entender como funciona isso. De qualquer forma, grato a ambos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode criar uma função para validar as informações passadas via `POST`:

```
<?php
function validarPOST( $arg )
{
    if( isset( $_POST[$arg] ) ) //CHECA SE FOI PASSADO VIA POST
    {

        $arg = trim( $_POST[$arg] );

        // CHECA SE O VALOR PASSADO É NULO, VAZIO, FALSO OU ZERO;
        if( $arg == null || empty($arg) || $arg == false )
        {
            return false;
        } else
        {

        return true;

        }

    } else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

Basta colocar seu código dentro de uma condição:

```
<?php
if( validarPOST('nome') && validarPOST('telefone') && validarPOST('endereco') && validarPOST('assunto') && validarPOST('msg') )
{
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $fone = $_POST['telefone'];
    $email = $_POST['endereco'];
    $assunto = $_POST['assunto'];
    $msg = $_POST['msg'];

    $conteudo = "<table width='600' border='0' cellspacing='2' cellpadding='2'>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan='1' align='center'><h3><em>Assunto do E-mail</em></h3></td>
                    </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td width='30%' bgcolor='#f0f0f0'><strong>Nome:</strong></td>
                            <td>$nome</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width='30%' bgcolor='#f0f0f0'><strong>Telefone:</strong></td>
                            <td>$fone</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width='30%' bgcolor='#f0f0f0'><strong>Email:</strong></td>
                            <td>$email</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width='30%' bgcolor='#f0f0f0'><strong>Assunto:</strong></td>
                            <td>$assunto</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width='30%' bgcolor='#f0f0f0'><strong>Mensagem:</strong></td>
                            <td>$msg</td>
                        </tr>
                </table>";
    $seuemail = "teste@teste.com.br";
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
    $headers .= "From:".$email." \r\n";
    $assunto = $assunto;

    $enviar = mail($seuemail, $assunto, $conteudo, $headers);

    if($enviar) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('Contato Enviado com Sucesso!'); window.location.href='contato.php'; </script>";
    }else{
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('Ocorreu algum erro ao enviar o formul&aacute;rio'); </script>";
    }
} else
{
    die("Informações faltando ou inválidas!");
}
?>
```

PS: Forma básica! Use essa ideia para implementar uma validação conforme sua necessidade.

Comment: Entendi a ideia LipESprY!
Mas não consegui implementar, sou um pouco leigo em PHP. A primeira e a segunda parte do código, utilizo no enviar-contato.php? Ou a primeira na página contato.php? Fiz o teste, enviei um formulário com tudo preenchido e ele deu a mensagem de erro no DIE.

Comment: Se você juntar esses dois códigos e substituir o seu, já vai ser uma mão na roda. Depois vc vai pesquisando/estudando sobre os comandos que utilizei pra vc melhorar o código.

Comment: Juntei os dois códigos e e acaba na mensagem de erro mesmo quando, testando no ar e tudo mais.

Deve ser algo que eu escrevi errado aqui. Mas muito obrigado mesmo!

Comment: Qual mensagem de erro?

Comment: Juntei os dois no enviar-contato.php, certo?
Aí entro no formulário mesmo, em contato.php, digito nome, endereço, etc... E clico em enviar, antes ele aparecia "Contato enviado com sucesso", conforme o alerta. Agora ele acaba em "Informações faltando ou inválidas!", mesmo preenchendo tudo e está do mesmo jeito que me passou.

Comment: Isso quer dizer que alguma das informações não estão sendo passadas pelo `$_POST`. Faça o seguinte: Apague tudo e deixe apenas `<?php print_r($_POST); ?>` na página que envia pra vc depurar. Confira todos os campos e veja o que há de errado. Se quiser, inicie um chat comigo que lhe ajudo. Lembrando: faça um backup da sua página!

Comment: Reputação baixa ainda, não dá para começar chat. hahaha.

Mas assim, eu fiz o <?php print_r($_POST); ?> apareceu tudo correto! Aí retirei o código que você sugeriu, deixei só o envio e me enviou no e-mail todos os campos, ou seja, todas as informações estão sendo passadas. Coloquei o seu código sugerido novamente e retomei o envio do formulário, apareceu o erro "Informações faltando ou inválidas!" de novo.

Comment: Corrigi a função. Tinha uma condição inválida. Agora deve funcionar. Teste aí. Se der certo, marca a resposta.